# Keyboard/trackpad blackout after battery replacement

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, battery, trackpad

I recently replaced the A1582 battery for 13" Early 2015 Retina MacBook Pro. Initially, it worked fine, but now the keyboard and trackpad lose connection (also the deeper click of trackpad), usually after the computer goes into stand-by. I can fix it by restarting the computer a few times and entering assisted mode and perform an SMC reset multiple times.

What can I do permanently fix this issue?

Comment: This is a long shot, but was the previous battery swollen? This can deform the top case and damage the connections and functionality of the trackpad -  in extreme cases, this is very easy see (the trackpad starts to life out of the case. Alternatively (and seems unlikely if the replacement was a new battery), maybe the new battery is over-sized (or already swollen) and thus pressing up against the trackpad?

Comment: No, the old battery was not swollen. I can check the replacement battery size, but yes, it was new and specific for the macbook model